# How to use class DTO in Salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to use class DTO in Salesforce LWC? How send DTO from @wire?

Example:

```
class MyAccountDTO{ public string Name; public string Email; public MyContactDto MyContactDto; }

class MyContactDto { public string Name; public string Phone; }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use @AuraEnabled:

```
class MyAccountDTO {
  @AuraEnabled public string Name; 
  @AuraEnabled public string Email; 
  @AuraEnabled public MyContactDto MyContactDto; 
}

class MyContactDto { 
  @AuraEnabled public string Name; 
  @AuraEnabled public string Phone; 
}
```

From there, you can simply return it as a normal value:

```
@AuraEnabled public static MyAccountDTO getAccount(Id accountId) {
  MyAccountDTO result = new MyAccountDTO();
  // ... //
  return result;
}
```

To get it via @wire:

```
@wire(getAccount, { accountId: '$accountId' })
  accountData;
```

If you need to send it:

```
@AuraEnabled public static someReturnType  sendData(MyAccountDTO accountData) {
```

...

```
@wire(sendData, { accountData: '$accountData' })
  wireResult;
```

Comment: how to save via form?

<lightning-input type="Text" name="Name" label="Name" value="{accountData.Name}" ></lightning-input>
<lightning-input type="Text" name="Email" label="Email" value="{accountData.Email}" ></lightning-input>
<lightning-button variant="base" label="Save"  onclick={save} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>

Comment: @WellingtonRodrigues You have to use imperative Apex calls, not a wire, in order to save data.

Comment: Thank you! @sfdcfox